# No applicable aggregate method 'OrderByDescending' exists'

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic-linq

in the regular linq its fine, but in dynamic linq doesnt have this method, how can i find a solution
Here is my error code in dynamic linq

```
q = " CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS.Count > 0 && CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS.OrderByDescending(ID_ASSENTAMENTO).FirstOrDefault().ID_PRIORIDADE == 2";
ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(q);
```

and my regular linq

```
ocorrencias = ocorrencias.Where(o => o.CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS.OrderByDescending(a => a.ID_ASSENTAMENTO).FirstOrDefault().ID_PRIORIDADE == 2);
```

Comment: What is the exact type of `o.CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS` here?

Comment: CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS IS List of object

Answer (score 0):

In your dynamic example you have

```
OrderByDescending(ID_ASSENTAMENTO)
```

You should provide a delegate like in the explicit Linq:

```
OrderByDescending(a => a.ID_ASSENTAMENTO)
```

Comment: dynamic linq doesnt read delegate
the error: 'No property or field 'a' exists in type 'CRM_ASSENTAMENTOS''

Comment: I think you will have to post your full code showing the compilation of the expression

Answer (score 0):

The inline `OrderByDescending(...)` is supported by [System.Linq.Dynamic.Core](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core)

For an example see this [QueryableTests.OrderByDescending.cs#L36](https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/blob/5863256c11e32b100c917d133c54bda4afae4d8a/test/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.Tests/QueryableTests.OrderByDescending.cs#L36)

Can you try that NuGet library?